# Call a member function from an activity, without starting that activity

Tags: android

In my application, there are two activity classes.  Suppose A and B.  Activity B has a member function name myfun(), Is it possible to call myfun of activity B from activity A with starting activity B.  If yes, please provide solution

thanks

Comment: please provide some code example, especially of your method that you would like to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initiate a object of your ActivityB, and than run the member function. (Use it like an normal object)

E.g

```
 ActivityB act = new ActivityB();
 act.yourMethod();
```

(the onCreate will not run when using the "new" keyword, only the constructor of ActivityB.)

Btw. If the method is not depending on any special state or member variables of the ActivityB class, I sugges you move/refactor the method to another Util class or something like that.

Comment: thank for your info, i simply checked, it is working, thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can create for sure, but you won't able to use that object to start activity, instead you can create a static method, or variable, and can use directly.

```
public static myFunction(int parameter)
{
   // Your code
}
```

and call this method by

```
YOurActivtiyClass.myFunction(parameter);
```